# Blind with negative margins

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using JQuery UI so that I can slide down a div using the blind function, however, it's not working properly.

Here's the JSFiddle I started: [http://jsfiddle.net/CBe3w/192/](http://jsfiddle.net/CBe3w/191/)

For some reason, the sides don't register until the sliding animation is done, at which point they pop out. How can I make it so that the sides are registered from start to finish (they should **always** be the width of the `box` class)?

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    Click Me!
    <div class="footer">
        Why does it do this?
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 25px;
}

.footer {
    background: red;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: -25px;
    margin-right: -25px;
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.box').click(function() {
    $('.footer').toggle("blind");
});
```

Comment: RELATED : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792341/jquery-ui-negative-margin-cut-div-on-effect

Comment: Bagwell, can you explain why you picked the html redesign solution ? Curious because my solution implied only 3 lines of css manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with the order in which jQuery changes the attributes of the element when it toggles it, and the fact that you have negative margins set on the footer.

You could potentially take off the left and right padding of .box, and then put your .box content in a separate div inside, which has margins.  Kind of a "hacky" way to do it potentially, though.

**Here's a potential solution**

The jQuery stays the same, only the CSS/HTML have changed.

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CBe3w/195/)

HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="content">Click Me!</div>
    <div class="footer">
        The sides don't pop out anymore!
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    width: 250px;
    /* took off the left and right padding */
    padding: 25px 0;
}

.content {
    /* "simulates" the padding of .box that you had before */
    margin: 0 25px;   
}

.footer {
    background: red;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    /* took off the negative margins */
    margin-top: 25px;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Josh Beam, i indented your .css part. Nothing major (except my 'indentation' mental disease).

Comment: @MilchePatern It's not a disease :) Add also `<!` between HTML and CSS code

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery UI at all: **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CBe3w/197/)**

```
$('.box').click(function() {
    $('.footer').slideToggle();
});
```

```
<div class="box">
    <h3>Click Me!</h3>
    <div class="footer">
        See how the sides popped Greatly?
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.box {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    width: 300px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.box h3{
    padding:25px 25px 10px;
}
.footer {
    background: red;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This looks right. You wouldn't really even need that H3 though, would you?  Unless just for the sake of it being semantic.  OP wouldn't have the issue of the sides "popping" in and out if he just changes toggle("blind") to slideToggle().

Comment: I didn't want to use slide() because it "squishes"/distorts the contents.

Answer (score 0):

**The explanation :** Jquery UI blind effect will set margin:0 while it's animating on the height of your element.

You will have to redesign your html to split your .box in order to remove it's padding, otherwise, patch jquery-ui javascript to remove that 'margin:0' from the effect er,

you'll be able to fix this issue by **positionning your inner container 'relative'**, so no html remake involved.

```
.footer {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF0000;
  display: none;
  left: -20px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[jsFiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/CBe3w/196/)